# How much monthly hours does the Scheduler addon take on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, scheduler, add-on, billing

In the Heroku documentation it's said that addons, such as Scheduler, add up to your montly hours, meaning you would have to pay if it adds up more than 30 hours (I have only one web dyno, so I'm using 720 montly hours, and the maximum free is 750 hours). So, how to calculate how much Scheduler takes from your montly hours? For example, if I have a **daily** task, how much would it take from my montly hours?

Comment: Can you confirm if what @Neil Middleton wrote in his answer is correct, about the billing of scheduler tasks. I'm also confused regarding the whole billing of scheduler-tasks.

Comment: I can't confirm it, I don't feel like doing the whole setup to test this, and I'm using my mom's credit card, so I can't see the billing info. I can't find it now, but I think that on 1 dyno we have 30 extra hours monthly to spare, and considering I never went even near to that, never worried about it.

Comment: But it says in the Heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#dyno-hour-costs, so I guess that's proof enough :)

Comment: "Dyno-hours from Scheduler tasks are counted just like those from heroku run or from scaled dynos." This has got me a bit confused. Does it mean that dyne-hours from scheduler tasks are added to the web-dynos, which serve the static pages?

Comment: Also, am I right when I say that it's not necessary that you will be using your whole set of 720 hours, if your website is only used by people from a certain geographical location & hence, can I remove those 6 hours when everybody sleeps from the 720 hours equation?

Comment: Yes, it means that it's added to the dyno-hours. I don't get it, why would it not hold for people in certain geographical locations? Yeah, I don't know about free apps, where the dynos get asleep after certain time of inactivity, if they still go to the dyno-hours if they're asleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the wall clock time of the time taken for the jobs that are executed by scheduler to run.

So, for instance, if you're running a 1 minute job every hour, you'd be looking at 720 minutes of time every 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this last answer is incorrect - the scheduler costs the same hourly as a regular dyno - right?